# Issue with negative numbers in NETWORKDAYS for Due and Performed dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to figure out how to use Conditional Formatting to setup so any dates under "Performed" regardless of before or after "Due" date will show specific formatting using NETWORKDAYS. Any dates of over 3 or more days (both plus and minus of "Due") will be red. And any dates of 2 or less days (both plus and minus of "Due") will be green.

I require these to be working/week days where if the "Due" date is e.g. 02 Nov 2020, and the performed date is 03 Nov 2020 (under 2 days) will be green. But if performed on the 28 Oct 2020 (as it is over 2 working days) will be formatted red.

[Excel showing image of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8m4c.jpg)

I have currently used the following codes:

```
=NETWORKDAYS($D$5,$E$5)<3

=NETWORKDAYS($D$5,$E$5)>3
```

The first for the green, and the second for red.

Any help will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute value in your formula? For example:

`=abs(NETWORKDAYS($D$5,$E$5))>3`